# Posterior Function of Bayesian Instrumental Variable Model

Tags: regression, bayesian, posterior, instrumental-variables

How does the posterior of a Bayesian Instrumental variable model look like?

I am aware that the Posterior $ \propto $ Likelihood * Priors. But I am not sure how the Posterior function looks like for an Instrumental variable model.

For eg, for a linear regression model ($Y = X \beta + \epsilon$), we have: 
Posterior $\propto$

[image: Posterior of Linear Regression Model]

[Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression]

**How would the Posterior change in the presence of an instrumental variable?** Say for example one independent variable $x_i$ is endogenous. and is given by the following equation: 
$x_i$ = $Z_i \gamma + \nu$

where $\epsilon$ and $\nu$ are error terms, $X$ is a set of independent variables, $Z$ is an instrumental variable and $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are unobserved coefficients to be estimated.

It would be very helpful if you could point me to an appropriate resource. Thanks in advance.

**Follow up question:** 
Following Professor Hanck's comment I looked up Greenberg Edn 1. 
On Pg 174, I see that the Likelihood function (assuming $x_is$ and $Y$ is **MVN**) is written as: 
[image]

Now what would happen if Y is not normal (for example: Poisson or logit). Would the likelihood function look this: 
[image] 
(Eq 1)

Or this: 
[image] 
(Eq 2)

Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: E.g., chapter 11 in Greenberg, Introduction to Bayesian Econometrics

Comment: Thank you for the reference Dr. Hanck. I looked up Greenberg and had a follow up question. I have attached it at the end of my original question. Please let me know if my question does not make sense. I am very new to Bayesian econometrics and am trying to learn more.